# Why is a positive angle defect sufficient for the existence of convex regular polytopes?

Tags: geometry, intuition, polytopes, platonic-solids

If we want to build a **convex** regular n-polytope, we can start with a regular (n-1)-polytope, arrange $k$ copies around each (n-3)-dimensional ridge, and fold into n-space. This gives an easy necessary criterion for the existence of the polytope $\{X,k\}$, where $3\le k$, namely
$$
\theta\{X\}<\frac{2\pi}{k}
$$
$\theta\{X\}$ is the dihedral angle of the regular (n-1)-polytope $X$.

What has bothered me for the longest time is this:

> Why is this also a sufficient condition?

I.e., how come the construction always works? I find it conceivable that you could start building a polyhedron around one corner, but then something would go wrong as you went around and connected more polygons to your shape.

You can of course just construct all the polytopes to prove existence. But I always thought there might be some underlying reason for it always working. I would also be happy for an intuitive/heuristic argument. Anything, really.

Comment: This bothers me too, now that you mention it. Considering that other than the really easy cases (polygons and the $n$-dimensional analogues of the tetrahedron, cube, and octahedron) there are only five regular polytopes, perhaps it is simply easier to demonstrate the fact on the individual polytopes. Or with that few cases, maybe we just got lucky.

Comment: Yes, I agree. If there is no known reason, I guess it points to it being luck. It certainly breaks down if we consider star polytopes. According to wiki, there are only 14 regular star polytopes, and infinitely many that fail.

Comment: I always accepted this fact as "lucky coincidence" and then was even more surprised to see that the same coincidence happens when constructing the 4-dimensional regular polytopes. Everything that fits around an edge (restricted by the dihedral angles of the regular polyhedra) extends perfectly to a regular 4-polytope. There are more such coincidences in even higher dimensions giving rise to the [semi-regular polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiregular_polytope) (not regular though). This seems to fade ...

Comment: ... For example, except for the 3-dimensional octahedron, none of its higher-dimensional generalizations can be used to build a vertex-transitive (convex) polytope one dimension higher. Now that I think about it, this might be because it has too large dihedral angles (I don't know their values). So it might well be, that everything that is possible numerically, fits perfectly together geometrically. And this is certainyl a fact that has to be explained.
However, I assume the magic does not happen at the levels of regular polytops, but already at the level of finite reflection groups.

Comment: @M.Winter Yes, I looked up all the dihedral angles, and as you say, "everything that is possible numerically, fits perfectly together geometrically", in any dimension. I also think that the finite reflection groups are important, as you say, and I would love to see an answer going in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, when now additionally restricting to **convex** regular polytopes, then you could refer to any of the classical text books on that subject, e.g. Coxeter's Regular Polytopes.

They all use your argument as a necessary restriction only. But then, for sufficiency of existance, they turn towards an explicite construction. (Which then mostly follows Wythoff's kaleidoscopical construction.)

The only thing on that track to be known additionally in advance is the group thoeretical derivation of the possible (here: finite) Coxeter (i.e. reflection) groups.

--- rk

Comment: Hm, I feared as much.

Answer (score -1):

Well, regularity usually is equated to flag transitivity. And so the local rule clearly is enough. It must not close somewhere up, rather it could wrap around the n-ball over and over again. That would be fully legal.

--- rk

Comment: Yes, I suppose, but the point is that that doesn't happen. We always get convex polytopes / tile the n-ball exactly once. Even if we allow to wrap around multiple times, there is the question of whether the figure would ever close (with finitely many layers). If it always did that, wouldn't there be infinitely many non-convex regular polytopes?

Comment: Neither polytope nor regularity restrict on convexity or finiteness. Consider the Kepler-Poinsot polyhedra, or regular tesselations or honeycombs. There even are regular skrew polytopes with non-planar vertex figures or faces. Moreover you not even are restricted to finite covers as for {5/2, 5}, but well can consider infinte covers as for {5/2, 4}. - If you don't want to encounter these, you explicitely have to rule them out.

Comment: Well, I do write in the first sentence: "If we want to build a convex regular n-polytope..."I guess I should add that to the title and make it more clear in the text.

Comment: In any case, I am interested in the fact that the construction/criterion always gets us a convex polytope. Even if we could say "anything is allowed to happen", the interesting thing for me is that only one thing happens, so is that provable or intuitive?